Will this linear motion idea work?
I"m not an engineer, although I have a PhD in Physics. I am designing some exercise equipment. I was wondering if you could look at this idea for linear motion.  It is my first try.   I'm sure it has problems, and I could use a more experienced set of eyes on it.   The main problem I see is that this idea requires a precise spacing of the vertical supports so that the wheels keep contact but don't put an inward pull on the supports. I can't be sure the fabricators will get this precision.  The verticals are 2" steel tubing, the spacing is about 36" or so. I was thinking that if there was a spring pulling the wheels to the middle, then that would keep the contact, but that solution would get ridiculously complicated.
This linear and vertical motion problem comes up repeatedly in my equipment. For the purpose of this question, I have reduced it to the simplest formulation of the problem.  But as an example, I might put weights on this horizontal part and then a person might push it up.   Or conversely, it could be hanging from springs above, and then a person would push down on it.  I"m sorry if my explanations are not adequate.  I can post images of the full exercise setup if needed. Thanks for your patience.


I think constant contact is needed to prevent the thing from coming off the tracks.  Also, the user who is pushing or pulling it up or down would probably want to experience a steady contact.

if you want to keep the bar horizontal at all times, then you need cables and pulleys,  or some type of rack and pinion arrangement, or perhaps use linear bearings ... if you want to simulate free weights then enlarge the openings at the ends of the horizontal bar so that the vertical bars have lots of room to move around

@jsotola.   I do want the bar horizontal.    It is probably obvious to you why this design won't work, but I guess I'm not smart enough to understand.  Could you explain why this design won't work?  I'd really appreciate it.

It will 'work' but the bar will tend to droop at one end or the other as the posts bend.

You will need additional horizontal bars to keep the two vertical bars at constant spacing, or the flexing in the vertical bars will lose contact on the wheels.  So your vertical bars should probably look more like a ladder (as many rungs as needed to keep them at constant spacing, could be just 2).  With that I think your idea would work.

There are many models commercially available.
This one is manufactured by MoveStrong. link
Or the next one from Amazon.

-

-
Edit
After the comment by OP.
This is a sliding compression lockup based on a metal ring barely larger than the shaft passing through it, being tilted by a spring and hence bite into the shaft and lock in any variable position.
This mechanism was used in the jack of the VW Beatle and some other vintage Europian cars.
.


Thanks very much for the link to the MoveStrong item.  I will keep that mechanism in my brain for future reference.  However, I'm looking for something that can move freely up and down.

@Chris, I edited my answer and added a detail more conforming to what you want. Check it out.

Thanks for the info about the jack in the VW bus.  I wonder if this is used in anything modern?
